# Automatically Log a User Out if They Log in on Another Device

Tags: ios, web-services, rest, authentication, access-token

I have an app which requires users to log in. Logging in is handled via a POST request to my back-end REST API, which generates a new access token if the login details are correct and returns it to the app (which is then saved in the keychain). My question is, how do I handle cases when a user logs in from multiple devices at once? The device who logged in first will not realize that their access token has expired, but will continue to try to send requests which will be denied (because the access token no longer matches the one stored in the database). I have thought about checking that the access token matches the database token in viewDidLoad in my AppDelegate, but this would only work when the app is first loaded. Is there best practice already established for this sort of thing? If so what is it?

The best solution I have thought of so far is to just re-issue the same access token each time the user logs in, but this seems insecure to me. Is this a safe way to handle it?

Comment: Sounds like you need to have a conversation with your server guy about how to determine whether a token is expired or not.  In my opinion, it should simply be a "logged in via some other device" or "token expired" error returned by the server.

Comment: I am the server guy. I know how to tell the client that the token is expired, I am asking when to expire the token and how to recognize/handle an expired token on the iOS side.

Answer (score 1):

It's a good practice to issue a new token on each sign-in. Tokens are meant to be expendable, and differentiating between user sessions on different devices and browsers is useful (see [Facebook's session management](https://www.facebook.com/help/www/174571515935086) for an example).

There are two possible ways to handle the double login scenario:

1. Maintain multiple active tokens for each user in your database and invalidate each on sign-out
2. Allow only one token per user, invalidating the existing token on sign-in

The choice depends on the nature of your application. In the second instance, the first client won't know that its session is invalid until the app makes a network call. At that time, your server should return a custom error to indicate that the token has expired. The app should then alert the user and return them to the sign-in screen.